# Android Chain Animations

Tags: android

I am attempting to "chain" two animations together, so when one completes, the other begins.  This is working except for one issue.  After the first animation is complete, it moves back to it's original position.  I am setting fill after to true.  What else am I missing?

Here is the code I am using.  Note, this is in a class that is extending LinearLayout.

```
// FIRST ANIMATION
mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, PANEL_END_X, 0, 0);
mAnimation.setDuration(PANEL_TRANSITION_TIME);
mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        // FIRST ANIMATION COMPLETE, CALL THE SECOND ANIMATION
        startAnimation(mAlphaAnimation);
    }
});

// SECOND ANIMATION     
mAlphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
mAlphaAnimation.setDuration(PANEL_ALPHA_TRANSITION_TIME);
mAlphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Solution:

The only way I could get this to work to my satisfaction was to use an `AnimationSet`, but set the starting offset of the second animation to start offset + duration of the first animation, plus a little padding.  They did not have to be completely exact in my case.

I tried playing with various values as CommonsWare suggested, but I would always get some type of "snapping" effect where the values would revert to their original value before taking the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After the first animation is complete, it moves back to it's original position. I am setting fill after to true. What else am I missing?

Animations are transient effects. If you want the effects to be permanent, you have to do that yourself in `onAnimationEnd()`. In the case of a `TranslateAnimation`,  you need to change the `LayoutParams` or something of the affected widget to permanently keep it in its end position. Or, if you are translating it off the screen, set the visibility to `View.GONE`.

Comment: The AnimationSet.Builder ended up being what I needed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder.html.

Answer (score 8):

I found what I believe to be the ideal solution in API level 11 and above using the [AnimationSet.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder.html) class.

> The Builder object is a utility class to facilitate adding animations to a AnimatorSet along with the relationships between the various animations. The intention of the Builder methods, along with the play() method of AnimatorSet is to make it possible to express the dependency relationships of animations in a natural way. Developers can also use the playTogether() and playSequentially() methods if these suit the need, but it might be easier in some situations to express the AnimatorSet of animations in pairs
>
> For example, this sets up a AnimatorSet to play anim1 and anim2 at the same time, anim3 to play when anim2 finishes, and anim4 to play when anim3 finishes:

```
AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();
s.play(anim1).with(anim2);
s.play(anim2).before(anim3);
s.play(anim4).after(anim3);
```

Comment: Note that this is only available on API Level 11 and higher, so Android 1.x/2.x devices cannot use it.

Comment: don't forget s.start() like I did

Answer (score 2):

Try combining them into an `AnimationSet`.

Comment: Doesn't that perform them both simultaneously though?  I want one animation to begin after the other is complete.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. I misunderstood this phrase in the Javadoc: "The transforms of the child animations are applied in the order that they were added"

Comment: That sentence is confusing, and seems to imply that it does what I want.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: I actually ended up using an AnimationSet, but set the start offset of the 2nd animation to be the start offset of the 1st + the duration of the 1st.  I tried CommonsWare answer, and while I believe it is the ideal solution, I could quite get the effect I needed.

Comment: Check the AnimationSet.Builder class out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder.html.

Comment: You can put AnimationSets on consecutive